# Unique combinations of all elements from long python list with elements from shorter list

Tags: python, combinatorics

I have two lists:

```
trips = ['trip1', 'trip2', 'trip3', 'trip4',...., 'tripN']

trucks = ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

I want to obtain all possible unique combinations so that all trips are matched with a truck in the trucks list. Please note, that all trucks must execute the same number of trips. In the above case for example if `len(trips) == 12` then all trucks must be matched with 4 trips each.

Moreover,

```
extra_trips = len(trips) % len(trucks). If extra_trips != 0
```

then get also all the unique combinations of trips-trucks by matching the remaining trip with whatever truck.
I have done the following but I have trouble to proceed:

```
import itertools
import random
trucks=['A','B','C']
trips = ['trip1', 'trip2', 'trip3', 'trip4']

combs= [list(itertools.zip_longest(trucks, x)) for x in itertools.permutations(trips,len(trips))]
```

From the above code, I get this output:

```
[[('A', 'trip1'), ('B', 'trip2'), ('C', 'trip3'), (None, 'trip4')], [('A', 'trip1'), ('B', 'trip2'), ('C', 'trip4'), (None, 'trip3')], [('A', 'trip1'), ('B', 'trip3'), ('C', 'trip2'), (None, 'trip4')], [('A', 'trip1'), ('B', 'trip3'), ('C', 'trip4'), (None, 'trip2')], [('A', 'trip1'), ('B', 'trip4'), ('C', 'trip2'), (None, 'trip3')], [('A', 'trip1'), ('B', 'trip4'), ('C', 'trip3'), (None, 'trip2')], [('A', 'trip2'), ('B', 'trip1'), ('C', 'trip3'), (None, 'trip4')], [('A', 'trip2'), ('B', 'trip1'), ('C', 'trip4'), (None, 'trip3')], [('A', 'trip2'), ('B', 'trip3'), ('C', 'trip1'), (None, 'trip4')], [('A', 'trip2'), ('B', 'trip3'), ('C', 'trip4'), (None, 'trip1')], [('A', 'trip2'), ('B', 'trip4'), ('C', 'trip1'), (None, 'trip3')], [('A', 'trip2'), ('B', 'trip4'), ('C', 'trip3'), (None, 'trip1')], [('A', 'trip3'), ('B', 'trip1'), ('C', 'trip2'), (None, 'trip4')], [('A', 'trip3'), ('B', 'trip1'), ('C', 'trip4'), (None, 'trip2')], [('A', 'trip3'), ('B', 'trip2'), ('C', 'trip1'), (None, 'trip4')], [('A', 'trip3'), ('B', 'trip2'), ('C', 'trip4'), (None, 'trip1')], [('A', 'trip3'), ('B', 'trip4'), ('C', 'trip1'), (None, 'trip2')], [('A', 'trip3'), ('B', 'trip4'), ('C', 'trip2'), (None, 'trip1')], [('A', 'trip4'), ('B', 'trip1'), ('C', 'trip2'), (None, 'trip3')], [('A', 'trip4'), ('B', 'trip1'), ('C', 'trip3'), (None, 'trip2')], [('A', 'trip4'), ('B', 'trip2'), ('C', 'trip1'), (None, 'trip3')], [('A', 'trip4'), ('B', 'trip2'), ('C', 'trip3'), (None, 'trip1')], [('A', 'trip4'), ('B', 'trip3'), ('C', 'trip1'), (None, 'trip2')], [('A', 'trip4'), ('B', 'trip3'), ('C', 'trip2'), (None, 'trip1')]]
```

As you can see, it returns some combinations but for every comb, one trip is not matched.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that this is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, please always include the tag of the language you are working with. This way, more people can find your question and won't have to go looking for what programming language you're using.

Comment: "I want to obtain all possible unique combinations so that all trips are matched with a truck in the trucks list." I can't understand the description. Could you show a few possible outputs? Do you know how many outputs there should be, for this input? Are you able to solve the problem by hand for a small input?

Comment: It sounds like the goal, for the 12 trip / 3 truck case, is to *choose* 4 trips (without replacement or reordering) that correspond to truck A, 4 for truck B and 4 for truck C, correct? If I understood it right, then the possibilities for truck A are combinations (not permutations) of 4 of the original 12; in each of those sub-cases, the possibilities for truck B are combinations of 4 of the other 8; the possibilities for C are pre-determined.

Comment: "Moreover, extra_trips =..." I can't understand what this is supposed to tell us. Suppose for example that there are 11 trips and 3 trucks. Exactly what should happen? Should every trip be attempted by a truck, or will each output possibility leave two unassigned trips? If every trip is assigned, what is the rule for how they are divided up?

Comment: Hi Karl, I think you understand it quite good yes. regarding the extr_trips, that's just the remainder of the division nr_of_trips/nr_of_trucks. For the 12 trip/ 3 trucks case that is zero so no worries. But for the 4 trip/3 trucks case, that means that in every comb, where each truck is matched with one trip, one truck has to be matched also with this "extra_trip". That generates even more combinations as I would like to return all possible unique combinations for the 'orphan' trip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `zip_longest` sort of sounds like the right approach, but you need to [`cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) the shorter list so that if they don't share a common divisor some trucks will get repeated.

```
from itertools import cycle

def zip_cycle_shorter(a, b):
    if len(a) < len(b):
        a = cycle(a)
    elif len(b) < len(a):
        b = cycle(b)
    return zip(a, b)

list(zip_cycle_shorter([1,2,3], ['a','b','c','d','e']))
```

gives me: `[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (1, 'd'), (2, 'e')]`

which is what I think you want.  It might be instructive to try generalising this to support an arbitrary number of lists.  For example, try filling in code to complete:

```
def zip_cycle_shorter(*lists):
   ...
```

(you just use comprehensions instead of handling each case specifically)

Comment: That was brilliant thank you Sam!

Comment: Well, do you maybe have an efficient way to drop duplicates? Because when I implement your function to my code to get the combs, the amount of combs I get for 9 or 10 trips is extremely large due to duplicates. I manage to drop them in another line however when the case is 12 trips / 3 trucks the combs get outstandingly large with duplicates and takes too long to calculate

Comment: all permutations of a long list will always be a lot of items, you probably want to change your algorithm so you don't need to calculate it directly.  e.g. have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

Comment: that said, my code won't give duplicates, so you might want to look at why your code is making duplicates in the first place

Comment: I mean I use your code in mine above like this: combs = [list(zip(cycle(trucks), x)) for x in itertools.permutations(trips,len(trips))] .   This produces many dublicate entries in t and the more the trips the more the dublicates. When I drop them I get the desired result however when trips are many then the dublicates are so many that it takes ages. I was wondering if you have any smart way to avoid them

Answer (score -2):

You only need to do the cartesian product of the two lists:

```py
trucks=['A','B','C']
trips = ['trip1', 'trip2', 'trip3', 'trip4']

print([(truck, trip) for truck in trucks for trip in trips])
```

Result:

```
[('A', 'trip1'), ('A', 'trip2'), ('A', 'trip3'), ('A', 'trip4'), ('B', 'trip1'), ('B', 'trip2'), ('B', 'trip3'), ('B', 'trip4'), ('C', 'trip1'), ('C', 'trip2'), ('C', 'trip3'), ('C', 'trip4')]
```

Comment: That doesn't help much. The code:

Comment: @Fotis here you have an explanation of (cartesian product)[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product] that's exactly what you're searching I think.

Comment: This is not what they asked for at all.

Comment: Yeah, I saw it after @CrazyChucky, take it easy.